# How to port a asm code to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, x86, inline-assembly

The following code should work at Linux. I want port the following code to Visual Studio 2008, but I am not very familiar with asm code. Could you help me?

```
#include <stdint.h>
static inline uint32_t log2(const uint32_t x) {
   uint32_t y;
   asm ( "\tbsr %1, %0\n"
     : "=r"(y)
     : "r" (x)
    );
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC uses the [AT&T syntax](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html). MSVC uses Intel syntax. That function would look something like this (compiles with MSVC 2010 /`16.00.40219.01`, but I see no reason why it would fail on 2008):

```
static inline uint32_t log2(const uint32_t x) {
  uint32_t y;
  __asm {
    bsr eax, x
    mov y, eax
  }
  return y;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to save/restore `eax` in an asm block in MSVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06%28v=vs.90%29.aspx